# How to get order of text files generated across different systems (Windows system and Android phone)?

Tags: c#, android

I am developing applications for both Windows system(using C#) and Android phone. These applications allows user to upload data(data can be text only at present) on the server. If the user is offline, the data is saved in the respective systems locally. When the user is online, the data is sent to server in the same order as it was created. These two applications are for user's convenience so that whichever system is available to user at a particular time, the user can use that to upload the data. Now the problem is that the order of the documents in which they were created can be known for that system only which was used to create the same. Is there any way that we can get the order across the systems. e.g. The user wrote some text for upload using Android phone which was saved locally on phone because user was offline. Next time user wrote a text from Windows system which was also saved locally. Now when both are supposed to uploaded how can we know the order in which they were created.

At first, I thought of using local system time for this purpose but it can change. And in that case the order will get messed up.

I also thought of creating my own clock i.e. when the user is online it will get time for server and after that it will calculate time on its own. But I am stuck because if the system/phone is switched off, the application will not run anymore and hence lose track of time.

The next thing which follows up is to get time from system rtc. In case of Windows(C#) it is same as what we get from

```
DateTime.Now
```

which will return the current system time which can be wrong also. What is the best possible answer for this situation.

Is getting time from server and setting system's time to the same is a good idea?

I am open to suggestions, discussions and any other ideas.

Comment: One option is to access the user's camera, scan the image for a clock, then use a pattern recognition algorithm to read the current time from that clock.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you please explain it in little more detail?

Comment: It was more of a joke, but I'm sure someone would be able to tell you how. See my answer below for a slightly more realistic solution.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but if your device has a GPS receiver then you can use that to get the current time from a master clock.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your synchronization process to this:

1. Get the server's DateTime
2. Get the local system's DateTime
3. Get the file's "last modified" DateTime
4. Calculate the difference between (1) and (2), minding possible time zone differences
5. Add (3) and (4) together to get the real "last modified" DateTime

**EDIT**

This simple algorithm will work only if:

- The local clock has simply gone out of sync (as clocks tend to do)
- The local clock was never properly configured (e.g. count started at 01/01/1900)

This algorithm fails when:

- A user intentionally changes the local time settings
- A user intentionally changes a file's timestamp

The question is whether the last 2 cases are really worth accounting for?

Comment: Changing system's date and time doesn't change file's "last modified" DateTime in Windows. Please explain how file's "last modified" DateTime is gonna help.

Comment: If the local time was already off when the file was last modified, then so is the file's timestamp. You can add all sorts of additional checks to your app, but the idea remains.